# ArrayList.toString без запятых

Tags: java, массивы, конвертация

Всем привет.

Есть `ArrayList<Character>`, каким образом его можно конвертировать в строку и вывести её на экран без запятых? В таком варианте:

```
System.out.println(massStringList.toString());
```

После каждого символа вставляются запятые. Сама строка имеет свои запятые, поэтому удалять все не вариант.

Полный вид строки, которая должна выводиться:

```
String s = "Текст, текст, текст, текст";
char[] massString = s.toCharArray();
int len = massString.length;
Character[] array = new Character[len];
for (int i = 0; i < len ; i++) {
    array[i] = new Character(s.charAt(i));
}
ArrayList<Character> massStringList = new ArrayList<>(asList(array));
```

Строка вначале конвертируется в `char[]`, а потом в `Character[]`, чтобы можно было из массива символов сделать `ArrayList`. Тоже костыли, да. И нужен именно `ArrayList`, просто массив не подходит.

Интересует как это можно можно сделать именно API джавы, через `for` сделать могу, но это какие-то костыли получаются, как например:

```
for (Character chr : massString)
{
         System.out.print(chr);
}
```

Встретил тут пару обсуждений на похожую тему, но кроме означенных костылей ничего не увидел.

Comment: Перечислите пожалуйста в вопросе списком какие решения вы считаете костылем. А то глядишь и посоветовать нечего будет

Comment: Алексей Шиманский, добавил.

Comment: @kamradserg добавьте пример с содержимым ArrayList

Comment: а как насчет Java stream api Join()?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, если не сложно, прошу развернуть.

Comment: @LexHobbit, добавил.

Answer (score 6):

```
String str = String.join("", massStringList);
System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: пишет cannot resolve method

Comment: @kamradserg этот метод в Java 8 появился.

Answer (score 1):

Можно реализовать следующим образом перевод в список и обратно:

```
String s = "Текст, текст, текст, текст";

// Convert to list
List<Character> list = IntStream.range(0, s.length())
    .mapToObj(s::charAt)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

// Convert to string
String result = list.stream().map(c -> "" + c).collect(Collectors.joining());

System.out.println(result);

// Out: Текст, текст, текст, текст
```

Answer (score 0):

```
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner("","Out: ","");
list.forEach(sj::add); // или любой другой цикл.
System.out.println(sj.toString());
```